# Specify ProviderName in Connection to SQL Server from Asp.Net Core

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core

I have an Asp.Net core website that connects to a database on a different server. We have two web servers. Essentially they are configured the same, but on one web server, SQLExpress is installed. This seems to be creating a problem. Neither web servers have SQL Server installed, as I said the database is on a separate server.

On the server without SQL Express this appsettings.json works:

```
{
      "ConnectionStrings": 
      {
          "DefaultConnection": "Server=99999.ad.xxxx.co.uk;Database=SomeDBName;Trusted_Connection=True;"
      }
}
```

On the server with SQL Express installed the same AppSettings.Json creates the following error in the event log:
"Login failed for user 'DomainName\UserName'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database. [CLIENT: 999.999.999.99]. The Source of the error is MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS. Keywords are Classic, Audit Failure.

Is there a way around this without removing SQL Express?

In web.config the providername was specified as part of the connection but this doesn't seem to have any effect in AppSettings.Json (the error still occurrs) when I add it to the AppSettings.Json as follows:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "providerName": "System.Data.SqlClient",
"DefaultConnection": "Server=VDED11329.ad.axco.co.uk;Database=Migration;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with provider type. And in your second code snippet, "providerName": "System.Data.SqlClient" doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Here is the an example of connecting via web.config as is done in dot net framework. Note the use of ProviderName which is telling it to use SQL Server  <connectionStrings>
  <add name="CustomerDataConnectionString" 
    connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=Northwind"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>

Comment: I still haven't found how to solve this problem. However, in this case I was able to remove SQL Express from the web server as it wasn't being used. That fixed the issue but I still don't have any idea why having SQL Express on the web server would cause a problem as it wasn't the Server being referred to in the connection string.